Sync an oracle db to starrocks using flink
I am setting up a synchronization between oracle and starrocks following the steps in the docs . But I keep getting this error

Flink SQL> [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.InternalTypeInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4229340760390051770, local class serialVersionUID = 5235578560101400674

